# mysql select where left join syntax

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have a problem. I have 2 database tables.

table 1 people:

```
+----------+--------------+
|  id      | name         | 
+----------+--------------+
| 1        | johanalj     | 
| 2        | hjgjhggjh    | 
+----------+--------------+
```

table 2 images of people:

```
+----------+--------------+----------------+
|  id      | url          | people_ID      |
+----------+--------------+----------------+
| 1        | 3765345.png  | 1              |
| 2        | 87e58974.png | 1              |
+----------+--------------+----------------+
```

Now I want to select person with id 1 from table 1 and all pictures from table 2 that have people_ID 1.

I tried LEFT JOIN in combination with a WHERE but cant get it to work

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people p LEFT JOIN images i  ON  i.people_ID = p.id WHERE id = '1'";
```

But I get a no result massage. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you don't need a join

Comment: Id is ambigious, just define `p.Id='1'`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an error(ambiguous column id). Both tables have `id` column. You need to add the table alias with `id`. try with -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people p LEFT JOIN images i  ON  i.people_ID = p.id WHERE p.id = '1'";
```

Comment: I have a question, what are 'p' and 'i' ?? select * from people `p` left join images `i`

Comment: They are aliases of the tables.

Comment: aha, you mean is `AS`?  if yea, why didn't use it ?

Comment: aha, got it. but i don't know that it will work everywhere? Can I never do not use `AS` ? In other word, where i'm force to use `AS` ?

Comment: you can do without that.

Comment: You can use AS when renaming a column, for instance `SELECT id AS MyId FROM.....` or when ending a `CASE WHEN....END AS ColumnName`